# Check what process is spiking the average load with atop

Tags: load-average, atop

In trying to find the culprit of a high load average on a system during night (which does not seem to be related to logrotate) I installed atop to write a raw file with a specific interval. While reading the file, it seems the processlist stands still, can I somehow go back and forth between the samples to see what sticks out, and further sort by any column (like cpu usage)?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your second question, the list printed by `atop` is sorted by cpu usage by default. If you want to sort it by other parameter (like resident memory consumption) you can do that (`man atop` tells you how for both the interactive and the raw file modes).

Regarding your first question, this small AWK script may help:

```
BEGIN {
  printline = "false"
}
{
   if (printline == "true") { print($0); printline = "false" }
   if ($1 == "PID") { printline = "true" }
}
```

Run it as `awk -f myScript.awk logFromAtop.log` and it will give you the top line of atop for every interval; it will probably be easy to see the few lines that stand out. (The script just looks for the lines that start with PID and prints the next ones.)

Depending on your version of atop, it may give you an ASCII or binary raw file depending on the flags when you run it. In the latter case, you can get an ASCII version with `atop` itself, e.g. `atop -r binary.raw > logFromAtop.log`.

Comment: Thanks, but I use the raw mode of atop since I thought that would be a lot cleaner given I could forward and reverse between the takings. I might try writing the output to a file instead for sake of simplicity, unless you know how to properly use the raw files.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. My answer is about the _raw_ file produced by atop, not about atop's interactive mode.

Comment: @sergut - I'm confused, is that comment from the OP? The usernames don't match. You answer sounds fine to me too.

Comment: Thanks, @slm. I am a bit confused as well, and unsure whether my answer was useful or not...

Comment: atop raw file is, at least on my system which is linux 2.6, produces some kind of binary format.

Comment: This depends on the version. I have edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You will never discover what process is causing high average loads looking at the CPU % usage. Load average depends on whenever a process is running (R) or waiting for I/O (D). So the actual option you should use is `s`:

> `s`
>       **Show scheduling characteristics.**
>
> Per process the following fields are shown in case of a window-width of 80 positions: process-id, **number of threads in state
>   'running' (R), number of threads in state 'interruptible sleeping'
>   (S), number of threads in state 'uninterruptible sleeping' (D),
>   scheduling policy** (normal timesharing, realtime round-robin, realtime
>   fifo), nice value, priority, realtime priority, current processor,
>   status, exit code, state, the occupation percentage for the choosen
>   resource and the process name.
>
> When more than 80 positions are available, other information is added.

Just change your configuration to show scheduling characteristics and you will find the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

Run `atop` with the `-r` argument followed by your log file :

Then, while `atop` is running you can use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to see the next page, or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to see the previous one.